# add column to table and fill it under condition -mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table of hotels with rooms type and price for night.
i need to add to this table a column called `cheap/expensive` and fill it with conditions:
if the room price< 100 then fill in 'cheap'
else fill in 'expensive' .
how can i do it ?

I started with :

```
ALTER TABLE rooms 
ADD `cheap/expensive` CHAR NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Why do it all since it is easily derived but if you must consider a generated column. BTW cheap today is expensive tomorrow

Comment: It would probably be a better design to have a 'cheap' column with a '1' for cheap and a '0' for expensive.  Make it a TINYINT and save some space.  Or make it an INT and use it for ranges (i.e. 0 for no info, 1 < 100, 2 < 200, 3<300, ....) to be able to prove range searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is derived and subjective information, it's more likely something you would do in your code or query than directly as data in your database. For example, if you later update a price, you'd have to be cognizant of whether to update whether it's cheap or expensive. Or if you later decide to change the dividing line (e.g. to $110 or as a function of average household income), or that you need more fine-grained price categories (e.g. Cheap|Moderate|Expensive), it's easier and safer to change your algorithm rather than change your data.

Example query:

```
SELECT *, IF (price < 100, "Cheap", "Expensive") as price_category FROM room;
```

Comment: one little problem - if in the same hotel i have two types of rooms -one >100 the second<100  the result need to be only 'cheap'. what is the syntax for that?

Comment: @LidorIluz First, is it just as simple as you've stated? Is your algorithm that a hotel is "cheap" if it has any room types that are cheap? What if has 3 room types, at $99, $199 and $299? The average room type is $199. So is that still a cheap hotel? Might it not also be a function of the number of rooms at each price point? What if the only $99 room is the one overlooking the dumpsters? The more complex your algorithm, the more you'll probably want to move it into code.

Comment: @LidorIluz
Your system really calls for more than one table. But if you really want to do this all in one table with one query, then you'll need to group by hotel (presumably you have a hotel id in there somewhere), and then an aggregate function to coalesce your price category. If you didn't want to make your own, you could  get away with MIN(price_category), since "Cheap" lexicographically precedes "Expensive". Depends on how quick and dirty you're willing to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would name it either `cheap` or `expensive`, not `cheap/expensive`. And the value of that should be (if column name is `expensive`): 1 - for expensive, 0 - for cheap. With integer values it's faster and takes less storage.

```
ALTER TABLE rooms 
ADD `expensive` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Then you should have conditions before each insert to table with proper language you use, Java, PHP, Python etc.

Other way is to use `TRIGGERS`, but I wouldn't recommend that solution if you use backend language to verify your data.

Example trigger for this column when inserting new rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER expensivecheck BEFORE INSERT ON rooms FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.price >= 100 THEN SET NEW.expensive = 1; END IF;
```